# Having trouble validating user input with regex with JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a complete noob at this stuff.
But my goal here is to accept a certain username and validate it with a certain password.
I've searched and searched all night to no avail so here I am looking for an answer.

My code in html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="loginForm">
  <label for="userName" accesskey="F"><br>Username:</label>
  <input type="username" name="userName" id="userName">
  <label for="password"><br>Password:&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

My code in a seperate javascript file (which is being called by the html file):

```
function validate(id) {
  var guest1User = /guest1/;
  var guest2User= /[guest1]/;
  var guest1Pass= /[guest2]/;
  var guest2Pass= /[guest1]/

  var userCheck= document.getElemetnById(userName);
  var passCheck= document.getElementById(password);
  if (guest1User.test(userCheck.value)) {
    if (guest1Pass.test(passCheck.value)) {
      return true;

    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
  }
  if (guest2User.test(guestCheck.value)) {
    if (guest2Pass.test(passCheck.value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
      return false; 
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
validate();
```

Comment: What errors do you get? You seem to be calling *validate* immediately after the declaration, which doesn't seem appropriate. Surely it should be called when the form submits? `var guest2User= /[guest1]/;` does not seem correct.

Comment: yes I mean't it to be guest2. I'll try adding it to on submit.

Comment: would i just add         <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button> ?? I know that's wrong because how would the js file know that it's function was called?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

As per your comment you were wondering how would the js file know that its function has been called.... therefore you need to include the js file in the html file in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

make sure the path to the somefile.js is correct for example if your file system is like that:

/root/js/

/root/html/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/somefile.js"></script>
```

and your html file is inside the html folder then you refer to the js file as:

```js
function validate(id) {
  var guest1User = /guest1/g;
  var guest2User= /[guest1]/g;
  var guest1Pass= /[guest2]/g;
  var guest2Pass= /[guest1]/g;


  var userCheck= document.getElementById('userName');
  var passCheck=document.getElementById('password');
  
  if (guest1User.test(userCheck.value)) {
  console.log("true");
    if (guest1Pass.test(passCheck.value)) {
          console.log("true");
          return true;

    } else { 
        console.log("false");
        return false; 
    }
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("false");
    return false;
  
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/somefile.js"></script>
-->
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" method="POST" id="loginForm">
  <label for="userName" accesskey="F"><br>Username:</label>
  <input type="username" name="userName" id="userName">
  <label for="password"><br>Password:&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <input type=submit onclick="return validate();" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did everything just like that but it still isn't happening :/

Comment: So it is now only checking to see if I have input in the boxes, not validating whether or not it is the correct input.

Comment: This is giving me the biggest headache.